# When do we use wp_slash?

Tags: core

I read the [doc](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_slash/) but couldn't understand when I need to use wp_slash.

It says...

> This should not be used to escape data going directly into an SQL
> query.

Does it mean if I'm duplicating a post, I do not need to use wp_slash?

Answer (score 1):

Correct, if you are duplicating a post in WordPress, you do not need to use `wp_slash()` to escape the data.

The purpose of `wp_slash()` is to add slashes to the data to prepare it for storage in the database. When you are duplicating a post, you are not directly inserting or updating data in the database, so `wp_slash()` is not necessary.

The caution against using `wp_slash()` to escape data going directly into an SQL query is because it is not a secure way to protect against SQL injection attacks. Instead, you should use prepared statements or other techniques to properly escape data before including it in an SQL query.

Comment: will the data not escaped direct when we using wp_insert_post and update_meta?

Comment: wp_insert_post() function does perform some escaping and sanitization on the data you pass to it, but it's always a good practice to sanitize and escape your data before passing it to the function, especially if the data is coming from untrusted sources such as user input.  In these cases, the data may not be sanitized or escaped properly, and using wp_slash() can add an extra layer of security to your code by ensuring that the data is properly sanitized before being passed to wp_insert_post().

Comment: ah okay thanks i was looking a little in the code of wp like add_meta  and see them strange things todo.(like unspash in the method) Its kind of confusing when your from a world with pdo prepare ( i also saw that wp does prepare and have not to care